# What is the difference between multiple man pages of the same command?

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets, manpage

I started to learn socket programming for C / C++ and examining the man pages for functions like bind, listen etc.

While I was navigating between man pages, I noticed there are situations that there are multiple man pages for the same system call, e.g. socket()

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/socket.3p.html

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html

Among these manuals, what comes up at my linux box is the first one (socket(2)).

I noticed that one with the 3p suffix is titled "POSIX programmer's manual" and rest two are titled "Linux programmer's manual". Function prototypes and usages are the same (as far as I understood).

My question is: What is the purpose of two different versions of Linux Programmer's Manuals for the same system call, and what does the number between the paranthesis means (socket(2), socket(3p), socket(7))?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Man pages are organized in sections, each section have its own topic. Check out the manpage for `man`, try run `man man`, it lists all the sections available:

1. Executable programs or shell commands
2. System calls (functions provided by the kernel)
3. Library calls (functions within program libraries)
4. Special files (usually found in /dev)
5. File formats and conventions eg /etc/passwd
6. Games
7. Miscellaneous (including macro packages and conventions), e.g. man(7), groff(7)
8. System administration commands (usually only for root)
9. Kernel routines [Non standard]

For the `socket` example, "socket(2)" is the system call provided by the operating system kernel, "socket(3)" is the POSIX interface provided by the library, "socket(7)" is a general documents on the topic of socket. You can see that all three have different content.